# efficiently aggregate multi-row data in a single row representation in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have onehot coded pandas dataframe like following

```
p  c1 c2 c3
A  1  0  0
B  1  0  0 
A  0  1  0
A  0  0  1
B  0  0  1
```

I want to put the values of missing cells in one column from the following rows as follows

```
desired output

p  c1 c2 c3
A  1  1  1
B  1  0  1
```

Comment: `df.groupby('p').sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [463]: df.groupby('p').agg(sum).reset_index()
Out[463]: 
   p  c1  c2  c3
0  A   1   1   1
1  B   1   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = df.set_index('p').stack()
df = s[s.eq(1)].unstack().fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
df.shape()
```

Comment: someone posted this answer